# Send Viber Message as Self Bot

Tags: python, viber

how can I send a message as a self bot?

To send a message as a bot you whould do this:

```
from viberbot import Api
from viberbot.api.bot_configuration import BotConfiguration
from viberbot.api.messages import TextMessage
from viberbot.api.viber_requests import ViberMessageRequest
from flask import Flask, request, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

bot_configuration = BotConfiguration(
    name='YourBotName',
    avatar='http://avatar.example.com',
    auth_token='YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN'
)
viber = Api(bot_configuration)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def incoming():
    # Handle incoming messages
    viber_request = ViberMessageRequest(request.get_data())
    message = viber_request.message
    sender = viber_request.sender

    if isinstance(message, TextMessage):
        # Echo the received message
        viber.send_messages(sender.id, [
            TextMessage(text=message.text)
        ])

    return Response(status=200)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
else:
    print("Failed to send the message.")
```

But how whould you send a message as a self bot?
Also, a self bot is a bot that runs under the user account

I searched the internet and inspected network activity with WireShark to reverse engineer the Viber API but to no avail

Comment: as I know most messengers don't allow for `self bot` (and they can close your account if you will try to use `self bot`) - so you can't find any information.